# How to push scanned values to a stack in C?

Tags: c, arrays, stack, scanf

I guess there is a problem in scanning the values from keyboard to the stack array using scanf. I'm not sure how to enter scanned values to the array in the stack. Please correct my C code. Check my main method where I ask for user inputs and try to push them to the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define STACKSIZE 5

struct stack
{
    float data[STACKSIZE];
    int sp;
};

struct stack sta={{0},-1};

//push method
void push(float n)
{
    sta.data[++sta.sp]==n;
    //onlystack.data[++onlystack.sp]=x;  
}

//pop method
float pop()
{  
    return sta.data[sta.sp--];
}

//top method
float top()
{
    return sta.data[sta.sp];
}

//full method
int full()
{
    return (sta.sp==STACKSIZE-1);
}

//empty method
int empty()
{
    return (sta.sp==-1);
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    int temp;
    for (x=0; x<STACKSIZE; x++)
    {
        **printf("Enter float to be stored in the stack");
        scanf("%f", &temp);
        push(temp);**
    }

    while(!empty(sta))
    {
        for (y=0; y<STACKSIZE; y++)
        {
            printf("\t%f",pop());
        }
    }

    printf("%f", top());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts:

1. In `push()`, you test for equality instead of performing assignment.
2. `temp` is of type int. It should be a float.
3. `empty()` takes no arguments, and you pass it one.
4. The last `printf("%f", top())` will invoke undefined behavior, because you will print `sta.data[-1]`.
5. You don't really need the while loop and the for loop around the `pop()` printing. You should be able to just do the while loop.
6. To make your output more readable, you should probably print `'\n'` characters after each float, which will make each float be seen on their own line.

Once these errors are fixed, the code appears to work correctly:

- code: https://gist.github.com/sharth/3f67f2790e6a337ada47
- runtime: https://gist.github.com/sharth/fdd7af6d6630b335df09

Comment: So for the top function,

float top()
{
 return sta.data[0];
}

would be correct yeah?

Comment: I believe your `top()` function is currently implemented correctly. It's just that when you called it, there were no elements in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

A major problem here is that you give the format `"%f"` (for floating point) to [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), but you give it a pointer to an `int`. This will cause the value to be something completely unexpected.

Also, in the loop where you print the values, why have a nested loop? The outer loop is all that's needed.